# No available endpoints in a helidon-mp 4.0.0-M1 application

Tags: cdi, helidon

I am experimenting with 4.0.0-M1 and helidon-mp. I have a simple app, with a database connection. However I am using CDI and am wondering why no endpoints are exposed. All my endpoints on localhost:8080 yield a 404 (e.g. /health, /metrics, /rateMgmt/v1 - my endpoint ). I wonder if there is a special method to list all available endpoints or if CDI is not yet available in 4.0.0-M1.

This is my startup log:

```
2023-08-16 16:21:59 INFO  Version:150 - WELD-000900: 5.1.0 (Final)
2023-08-16 16:21:59 INFO  Bootstrap:67 - WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
2023-08-16 16:21:59 INFO  Bootstrap:228 - WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
2023-08-16 16:22:00 WARN  ServerCdiExtension:449 - There are no JAX-RS applications or resources. Maybe you forgot META-INF/beans.xml file?
2023-08-16 16:22:00 INFO  ServerListener:281 - [0x25f15f50] http://0.0.0.0:8080 bound for socket '@default'
2023-08-16 16:22:00 INFO  LoomServer:298 - Started all channels in 5 milliseconds. 4189 milliseconds since JVM startup. Java 20.0.1+9-29
2023-08-16 16:22:00 INFO  ServerCdiExtension:410 - Server started on http://localhost:8080 (and all other host addresses) in 4211 milliseconds (since JVM startup).
2023-08-16 16:22:00 INFO  HelidonFeatures:192 - Helidon MP 4.0.0-M1 features: [Server]
```

And I am wondering that CDI is not present in the features listed.

....

I can answer it by myself. I have created an uber-jar where apparently the CDI detection doesn't work.
With the slim jar I am getting on startup these logs:

```
[javax.sql.main.connection.url] VALUE 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/DEV_RAS_TST_S1_D1'
2023-08-16 18:56:27 INFO  VersionPrinter:42 - Flyway Community Edition 7.15.0 by Redgate
2023-08-16 18:56:27 INFO  BaseDatabaseType:42 - Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/DEV_RAS_TST_S1_D1 (Oracle 19.0)
2023-08-16 18:56:27 INFO  DbValidate:42 - Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.037s)
2023-08-16 18:56:27 INFO  DbMigrate:42 - Current version of schema "TST_S1_D1_OWNER": 3
2023-08-16 18:56:27 INFO  DbMigrate:42 - Schema "TST_S1_D1_OWNER" is up to date. No migration necessary.
Total Migrations : 0
2023-08-16 18:56:27 INFO  ServerCdiExtension:579 - Registering JAX-RS Application: HelidonMP
2023-08-16 18:56:28 INFO  ServerListener:281 - [0x315365ef] http://0.0.0.0:8080 bound for socket '@default'
2023-08-16 18:56:28 INFO  LoomServer:298 - Started all channels in 4 milliseconds. 10594 milliseconds since JVM startup. Java 20.0.1+9-29
2023-08-16 18:56:28 INFO  ServerCdiExtension:410 - Server started on http://localhost:8080 (and all other host addresses) in 10600 milliseconds (since JVM startup).
2023-08-16 18:56:28 WARN  scanner:208 - SROAP04005: Could not find schema class in index: io.helidon.examples.quickstart.mp.Models.RatePlanType
2023-08-16 18:56:28 WARN  scanner:208 - SROAP04005: Could not find schema class in index: io.helidon.examples.quickstart.mp.Models.RatePlanType
2023-08-16 18:56:28 INFO  HelidonFeatures:192 - Helidon MP 4.0.0-M1 features: [CDI, Config, Metrics, Open API, Server, WebServer]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as you have found out, Helidon does not support uber-jars.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).